# Rewriterule Q, example.com/xml/title/ to example.com/xml/index.php?var=title

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have example.com/xml/index.php and I want to access it with this url example.com/xml/title/ and last part would be GET var for index.php and it should show result using that var, what code should I add in my .htaccess file ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in the .htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^xml/([^/]+)/$ xml/index.php?var=$1
```

Comment: seems work, just one small issue it's working only with last slash
example.com/xml/title/ but isn't w/o that example.com/xml/title

Comment: @Tom: This this rule instead: `RewriteCond $1 !=index.php RewriteRule ^xml/([^/]+)/?$ xml/index.php?var=$1`